# How do I POST LF with curl command line tool?

Tags: linux, curl

I'm trying to POST to the HTTP gateway of an SMS provider (Sybase 365) using CURL from a Linux shell script.

I need to pass the following data (note the [ ] and LF characters)

```
[MSISDN]
List=+12345678
[MESSAGE]
Text=Hello
[END]
```

If I submit a file using the -F parameter, CURL removes the LF e.g.

```
curl -F @myfile "http://www.sybase.com/..."
```

results in this at the server (which is rejected)

```
[MSISDN]List=+12345678[MESSAGE]Text=Hello[END]
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid this or do I need an alternative tool?

I'm using a file containing my data for testing but I'd like to avoid that in practice and POST directly from the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got this working using -d

```
request=`printf "[MSISDN]\nList=$number\n[MESSAGE]\nText=$message\n[END]\n"`
response=`curl -s -u $username:$password -d "$request" http://www.sybase.com/...`
```

Curiously, if I use -d @myfile (where myfile contains LF separated text), it doesn't work.

I also tried --data-binary without success.

Answer (score 11):

Try using `--data-binary` instead of `-d(ata-ascii)`.

From the manual:

> --data-binary  (HTTP)  This posts data in a similar manner as --data-ascii does, although when using this option the entire context of the posted data is kept as-is.
>
> If you want to post a binary file without the strip-newlines feature of the --data-ascii option, this is for you. If this option is used several times, the ones following the first will append data.

ETA: oops, I should read the question more closely. You're using -F, not -d. But `--data-binary` may be still be worth a shot.

Comment: That's the conclusion I'd just come to as well :)

Comment: Aha! I'd been working from this page http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html which I've just realised is just usage - it doesn't mention --data-binary. I actually want to avoid using -F because I want to avoid using the filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a silly thought, but I don't suppose it actually requires CRLF instead of just LF?

Alternatively, have you tried using the [--data-binary](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) option instead of -F?

Comment: CRLF or LF - it doesn't make any difference - but until you and Athena made me aware of --data-binary, I couldn't send either. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl "url" --data-binary @myfile
```

posts new lines in the data [tested on curl 7.12.1]